# How do I use response from an web api returning an image?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have two web asp.net mvc based projects.

The first one has an image preview api, is implemented somewhat like this...

```
private async Task <HttpResponseMessage> GetImage(int id)
{
    string filePath = "abstractedforsimplicity.png";
    using(var file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 4096, true)) 
    {
        byte[] buff = new byte[file.Length];
        await file.ReadAsync(buff, 0, (int) file.Length);
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Content = new ByteArrayContent(buff)
        };
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
        return result;
    }
}
```

this works, I am able to show a preview with the following url - domain/api/image/3

Now I am a different application where I want to again make use of the same preview. I do not want to expose this api directly, so will be making a proxy api which will be making the call internally.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetImage(int id)
{
   string tempalteUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["rmgpubadmin:template-base-url"], id);
   WebClient client = new WebClient();
   byte[] bytes = client.DownloadData(tempalteUrl);
   // not very sure what should i do here ??
   return null;
}
```

I tried to converting the bytes to an object, but if fails with errors - System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException.

`The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 89-50-4E-47-0D-0A-1A-0A-00-00-00-0D-49-48-44-52-00 ...`

What should i be doing here?

Comment: Why are you returning null?  Why did you try to convert to an "object"? (object of what? it's already a byte array).  What happens if you just send the byte array on, ie use the exact same code:  `var result = new HttpResponseMessage { Content = bytes; }; ... return result;`

Comment: Yes. I actually got the answer as soon as I finished submitting the question itself. Thanks @freedomn-m for the answer :)